# Por que ao substituir todos meus "mysql" por "mysqli" meu projeto parou de funcionar?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

O que devo fazer?
Devo configurar no banco de dados?

Antes tudo funcionava normalmente, cadastro de usuários, login...

```
<?php
   $host ="localhost";
   $user ="root";
   $pass ="senha"; 
   $banco="usuarios";

   $conexao = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die (mysqli_error());
   mysqli_select_db($banco) or die (mysqli_error()); 
?>
```

Comment: Aparece alguma mensagem de erro? a extensão mysqli está habilitada? poderia colocar seu código.

Comment: Não aparece mensagem alguma, mas o formulário de login some quando clico em enviar.

Comment: Onde habilito esta extensão?

Comment: A tela fica em branco? crie um arquivo novo e coloqueo seguinte código `<?php phpinfo;` e procure por mysqli, se não va ate o php.ini e descomente a linha que tem o mysqli e reinicie o servidor

Comment: Não, o background fica. Vou tentar isso e te digo.

Comment: Vou tentar te ajudar ... mysqli_ tem que ter a seguinte conexão ao banco de dados: `$link = mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","banco") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));`... sem isso náo vai funcionar mais nada. Se tiver isso ok, as consultas se passam diferente também:  `mysqli_query($link, "consulta");` ... Veja se isto está ok e me fala !!!

Comment: Minha conexão está assim:

Comment: Coloque o código que está dando erro na pergunta.

Comment: Se mudou pra mysqli querendo melhorar a segurança, só isso não basta. Você precisa usar prepared statements.

Comment: <?php
$host ="localhost";
$user ="root";
$pass ="senha";
$banco="usuarios";
$conexao = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die (mysqli_error());
mysqli_select_db($banco) or die (mysqli_error());
?>

Comment: Certo, mas além da segurança tem o fato de que está obsoleto, então quero usar o mais atual.

Comment: Não tem um código específico que esteja dando erro, tanto que tudo funcionava normalmente com "mysql", eu apenas substitui todos "mysql" por "mysqli".

Comment: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysqli-connect.php ... vejá instruções neste página porque a sua forma de conectar e adicionar o banco não está correta para `mysqli_`.

Comment: Obrigado, vou ler agora mesmo.

Comment: Quer dizer, já que é isso, vou procurar e estudar. A página que você me enviou está indisponível no momento, mas já foi útil sua informação.

Comment: Pelo seu código, `mysqli_select_db` precisa de dois argumentos o primeiro a conexão e o segundo o nome do banco

Comment: Mas como funcionava antes? Chequei meu php e mysql são todos versão superior a 5. Estou lendo algo aqui.

Answer (score 4):

Aqui eu apresento conforme a documentação uma das formas exatas de se trabalhar com `mysqli_` que é bem diferente das consultas primárias do `mysql`. Primeiro, você já pode escrever as variáveis direto dentro da instrução como segue e aplicar o método demonstrado: Faça a conexão e guarde-a dentro de uma variável.

```
// Conexão com o banco de dados
$conecta = mysqli_connect("host", "usuario", "senha", "banco") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($conecta)); 

// Faça então qualquer operação do CRUD seguindo as diretivas abaixo: 
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM usuarios" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($consulta)); 

// Execute a consulta 
$resultado = $conecta->query($consulta);
```

Esta é só a base para se trabalhar com `mysqli_` e você também tem outra opção que é `PDO`. Estou adicionando também um `while` caso você precise retornar dados para comparação:

```
while($linha = $resultado -> fetch_assoc()){
    echo '<p>'.$linha["nome"].'</p>';
    echo '<p>'.$linha["cpf"].'</p>';
    // etc ...
};
```

Comment: Deixa ver se eu entendi, vou ter que refazer meu código? Não é só mudar "mysql" por "mysqli", mas a estrutura para, por exemplo, lançar dados no banco de dados e recuperá-los é um pouco diferente?

Comment: Sim porque é uma arquitetura diferente.

Comment: Refazer o código é essencial quando se busca segurança e eficiência. Eu recomendaria direto o `PDO`, é o tipo de mudança necessária que vale **muito** apena.

Answer (score 4):

Provavelmente você usa em todo o código as funções nativas: `mysql_query`, `mysql_fetch_array`, `mysql_num_rows` e etc...

Então para mudar, por exemplo, de: `mysql_query` para `mysqli_query`, é preciso mudar também os argumentos, passando o link no primeiro argumento e a query string no segundo argumento, e não apenas a query string como era antes, e isso faz você ter que modificar TODAS as querys do site.

Então já que está obrigado a modificar praticamente tudo, sugiro que já faça as modificações de acordo com o conceito que explico abaixo.

Eu costumo criar funções para todas as operações de DB, assim quando alguma modificação é necessária, modifico apenas nas minhas funções e não preciso mudar nada no restante do código, isso foi muito útil quando tive que mudar de `mysql_` para `mysqli_`, abaixo um exemplo:

```
include('db_functions.php');

$host ="localhost";
$user ="root";
$pass ="senha"; 
$banco="usuarios";

jaw_db_connect($host, $user, $pass, $banco);

$cliente_query = jaw_db_query("select * from clientes where email = '" . jaw_db_input($email_address) . "'");

if (jaw_db_num_rows($cliente_query) > 0) {
    $cliente = tep_db_fetch_array($cliente_query);

} else {
    // nenhum cliente
}
```

**db_functions.php**

```
  function jaw_db_connect($server, $username, $password, $database, $link = 'db_link') {
    global $$link;

    $$link = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $database);

    return $$link;
  }

  function jaw_db_error($query, $errno, $error) { 
    die('<div><b>' . $errno . ' - ' . $error . '</b></div><div>' . $query . '</div>');
  }

  function jaw_db_query($query, $link = 'db_link') {
    global $$link;

    $result = mysqli_query($$link, $query) or jaw_db_error($query, mysqli_errno($$link), mysqli_error($$link));

    return $result;
  }

  function jaw_db_fetch_array($db_query) {
    return mysqli_fetch_array($db_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  }

  function jaw_db_num_rows($db_query) {
    return mysqli_num_rows($db_query);
  }

  function jaw_db_input($string, $link = 'db_link') {
    global $$link;
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($$link, $string);
  }
```

Coloquei acima apenas as funções principais, mas basta incluir todas as funções que você for utilizar no site...

Usando esse sistema, você pode facilmente modificar a função `jaw_db_query` para que ela registre em um arquivo de log todas as querys e o tempo da execução delas, contabilize quantas querys foram executadas na pagina, some o tempo total e grave numa variável para você exibir no rodapé em ambiente de desenvolvimento, e isso ajuda muito a identificar querys com baixa performance, que podem causar sobrecarga no servidor...

Answer (score 2):

É necessario passar dois argumentos para `mysqli_select_db()`, o primeiro a conexão e o segundo o nome do banco, como sugerido no [link](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.select-db.php) passado pelo  @marcosvinicius

```
mysqli_select_db($conexao, $banco);
```

Ou fazer a conexão passando o nome do banco dessa forma:

```
$conexao = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $banco);
```